# Issue with android mobile (100vh and position fixed footer bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's [link](http://front.404-solution.com/elemental/test) to site.

Site doesn't have scroll (you can move by using arrows), body has `overflow:hidden`.

Body contains 3 blocks: `.main-content`, `.bottom1` and `.footer`

`.main-content` has `100vh`.

`.bottom1` and `.footer` have `position:fixed` both. 

`.Footer` has `bottom: 0`, `.bottom1` has `bottom: 80px`. 

Desktop works just fine: height is `100vh` and other blocks are at the bottom. ios mobile browsers are also fine. **But android browsers have huge height (like 3x bigger than expected) and user has to scroll down to see footer**. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: [Please submit your code onto StackOverflow rather than linking to your website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applying `position:fixed;` to `.main-content` will fix the issue.

```
.main-content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```